# SQL on SQL Server- unable to run query which is stored in variable and executed using exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute the following SQL in SQL Server 2008-

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar, @fullname nvarchar;

SET @fullname='1patents_corrected.csv';
SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent from ' + @fullname+ '     WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE = "char", FIELDTERMINATOR = "^", ROWTERMINATOR =  "\n" );'

EXEC(@sql)
```

However I am getting this error--

> *Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>
>   Could not find stored procedure 'B'.*

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE-- I changed the query viz. specified a size for each varchar variable. Now the code is like this--

```
 DECLARE @MyCounter int;
 DECLARE @Fileprefix nvarchar(1000), @Filesuffix nvarchar(1000), @fullname nvarchar(1000), @Counter_string nvarchar(1000), @sql nvarchar(1000);

 SET @MyCounter = 1;
 SET @Fileprefix= 'C:\Arvind_gpd\patents\';
 SET @Filesuffix='data_corrected.csv';

 WHILE (@MyCounter < 10)

 BEGIN;
 Set @Counter_string= Cast(@MyCounter AS varchar(1) );
 Set @fullname = (@Fileprefix+ @Counter_string + @Filesuffix );
 SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent from ' + @fullname+ 
 '  WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE = "char", FIELDTERMINATOR = "^", ROWTERMINATOR = "\n" );'
 EXEC(@sql);
 SET @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1;
 END;  
 GO
```

However I am now getting a different error--

```
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
```

Incorrect syntax near 'C:'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Now what am I doing incorrectly :( ?

Comment: print out the @sql string and take a look at it. This `+ @fullname+ ` probably needs to be `+ @fullname+ '`

Comment: @SQLMenace sorry that was a typo when I inserted the code into my edit :( ... now I have pasted the code directly from SQL Server Management studio into the edit above... still getting the same error :(

Comment: do this double the ticks ('') and get rid of double ticks (") ` SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent from ''' + @fullname+ 
 '''  WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR = ''^'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' );'
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the file name when using BULK INSERT.

Change

```
SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent 
from ' + @fullname+ 
WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE = "char", FIELDTERMINATOR = "^", ROWTERMINATOR ="\n" );'
```

to

```
SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent 
FROM ''' + @fullname + '''
WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR = ''^'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )'
```

You'll notice that I have instances of multiple single quotes bunched together.  Double single quotes stand for escape in SQL Server (ie. I am quoting a quote within another quote).

Also, I see you use a lot of semicolons in your code.  No need to put them in when you are writing in T-SQL

Comment: ["Not ending Transact-SQL statements with a semicolon" is deprecated and will be discontinued in a future release.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)

Comment: Whoa, didn't know that.  Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 7):

change

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar
```

to

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)
```

by default the size is 1

The same applies to `@fullname nvarchar;` give it a size

Comment: +1 that's a good piece of advice in general - **always** define an explicit length for any string-related items in SQL Server!

Comment: This is a horrible default. It should not have a default, or default to something reasonable.

Comment: @SQLMenace pls refer my update- now I am getting a different error :(